# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) on expo for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am having my mobile application made using expo and I am getting the below crash for one of our user.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  4

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x196091e48 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18f35b8d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1961fe774 -[NSException init] + 0
3   aLexapp                                0x104a0758c 0x104968000 + 652684
4   aLexapp                                0x104a06254 0x104968000 + 647764
```

Also, the app crashes randomly. The same app works for her sometimes and sometimes it crashes. I am not able to trace the reason for crash. iOS 16.2 iPhone 13 Pro Max is the device of crash.